# Getting Later Date from Database without counting Filtered date

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Im trying to get "greater"/later date from database with query below

**Controller**

```
string str = "2019-10-27T20:44:55.323";
DateTime Date = Convert.ToDateTime(str);

var List = (from a in dbcontext.system_notification where a.notification_date  > Date select a).ToList();
```

**Output**

I still got result from **date** "2019-10-27T20:44:55.323".
Im expecting to get only **Later date** from date given since im using ">" operator.

Thank You!!

Comment: Did any of this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

> The DateTime struct represents dates as a 64 bit number that measures the number of “ticks” since a particular start date. Ten million ticks equals one second.

See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime/

Now, compare this to the [data types of MS SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeDataTypes):

> datetime  accuracy: 0.00333 s [ DEFAULT IN EF ]
>
> datetime2 accuracy: 100 ns

---

So, most likely, the value in your database is actually, sightly, bigger or rounded.

You can test this by checking the delta:

```
foreach (var dt in List)
{
   var delta = Date - dt;
   // check the value.
}
```

Comment: i see, i just know that . But any solution for this situation?. How to exclude filtered date from the result?

Comment: Well, your c# `DateTime` is equivalent to the sql `DateTime2`. So, you need to adjust your string to match the next available value. If you need this kind of precision you might want to change the sql type as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as below:

You should avoid using reserved words or keywords as a variable name.

```
string str = "2019-10-27T20:44:55.323";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(str);

var lst = dbcontext.system_notification.where(x => x.notification_date > dt).ToList();
```